# Minification breaks RGBA values in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, minify, rgba

So I am trying to set the border colors of a :before element using RGBA values. This works in all my desired browsers including IE. However if I minify the CSS, IE renders the border without color.

The code:

```
border-color: rgba(69,130,128,0.9) rgba(69,130,128,0.9) rgba(69,130,128,0.9) transparent;
```

When Minified:

```
border-color:rgba(69,130,128,0.9)rgba(69,130,128,0.9)rgba(69,130,128,0.9)transparent;
```

The work around for this is to set each border independently (border-top-color, border-bottom-color, ect...). However, I wanted to make sure that there wasn't a way to make the css when minified work correctly as I prefer to write a single statement rather than one for each location.

Here is a JS fiddle where the down state isn't working (is minified) and the hover state is.
http://jsfiddle.net/6uDn7/2/

Comment: it wants spaces between the values in ie, apparently

Comment: What version of IE are you using? There are bugs in various versions of IE and different levels of support for certain features.

Answer (score 1):

If you're minifying to shave weight consider the following:

- Standard readable css = 89 characters

  ```
  border-color: rgba(69,130,128,0.9) rgba(69,130,128,0.9) rgba(69,130,128,0.9) transparent;
  ```
- Non-working minified css = 85 characters

  ```
  border-color:rgba(69,130,128,0.9)rgba(69,130,128,0.9)rgba(69,130,128,0.9)transparent;
  ```
- [Working readable css using `border-color` and `border-left-color` = 65 characters](http://jsfiddle.net/6uDn7/6/)

  ```
  border-color:rgba(69,130,128,0.9); border-left-color:transparent;
  ```

Just trying to point out that minifying (removing white space) isn't always the best way to shave weight, you sacrifice readability and often function for a few bytes when you can usually save a lot more bytes and even make your code more readable by using shorthand properties and removing redundancy.